# How to add an Angular material custom mdToast with functions?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-material

I am building a project with Angular 1.x using Material ui framework and I stumbled upon weird issue where I cannot create a custom Toast (snackbar). More specifically I cannot add events to buttons on the Toast:

```
/// <reference path="../../_All.d.ts"/>

module MbRateDialog {
    class MbRateDialogController {
        static $inject = ['$location', '$scope', '$mdToast']

        constructor(private $location, private $scope, private $mdToast) {
        };

        closeToast() {
          console.log('closed');
          this.$mdToast.hide();
        }

        openToast() {
            this.$mdToast.show({
              hideDelay   : 0,
              position    : 'bottom left',
              autoWrap    : false,
              controller  : 'MbRateToastController',
              template    :
                  `<md-toast class="mb-rate-toast">
                      <div  class="mb-rate-toast__content">
                          <span class="mb-rate-toast__content-text">
                              Heading text
                          </span>
                          <div layout="row" layout-align="space-between center">
                              <mb-button type="primary" ng-click="this.closeToast()">Nope</mb-button>
                              <mb-button type="primary" ng-click="$ctrl.closeToast()">Yup</mb-button>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </md-toast>`
            });
        };
    }

    class MbRateDialogComponent implements ng.IComponentOptions {
        public controller = MbRateDialogController;
        public bindings: { [binding: string]: string } = {
            url: '='
        };
        public transclude = true;
        public template =
            `<div flex class="mb-rate-dialog">
                <mb-button type="primary" ng-click="$ctrl.openToast()">RATING</mb-button>
            </div>`;
    }
    angular.module('mbRateDialog').component('mbRateDialog', new MbRateDialogComponent());
}
```

The problem is that I cannot make the toast buttons use the same scope. At first I tried to inject `mdToastProvider`, but it instantly gave me errors, this way it works, but I cannot make the buttons do what I want.

Here is API for this: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdToast

I am pretty new to Angular, therefore I am a bit confused to controller setup for different scope. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Doesn't the "Custom Usage" demo explain it for you? https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/toast

Answer (score 0):

There is scope parameter in $mdToast.show method. Just provide desired scope.

You can pass your current scope or reuse newly created scope.

You can create scope via `childScope = $scope.$new();`